# connection to /run/my.sock failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: django, gunicorn

After I've updated code on my Django project and tried restarting the servise, I've started getting this errror:

```
2022-09-15 16:33:35 +0000] [695873] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-09-15 16:33:35 +0000] [695873] [DEBUG] connection to /run/my.sock failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied
[2022-09-15 16:33:35 +0000] [695873] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2022-09-15 16:33:36 +0000] [695873] [DEBUG] connection to /run/my.sock failed: [Errno ...
[2022-09-15 16:33:39 +0000] [695873] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2022-09-15 16:33:40 +0000] [695873] [ERROR] Can't connect to /run/my.sock
```

How do I diagnose the problem? Gunicorn logs don't say what's causing it. I didn't change configs. If I maid a mistake in the project folder, it still should have started. But there's no socket file in the `run` folder.

**UPDATE**
Found the problem. I accidentally deleted first opening bracket in my config file.

Comment: `my.sock` sounds like a (mysql) database connection.

Comment: @AKX .sock is how the HTTP Server (Apache/Nginx) communicates with the Django Project (Running by Gunicorn/Uwsgi) ..so how the front of the backend talks to the middle of the backend. -Just the more you know *rainbow*